# How to use proper OpenSSL version on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: curl, openssl, plesk, ubuntu-server

I have some troubles with OpenSSL.
I upgraded it to 1.0.2 manually (http://randombio.com/linuxsetup54.html with SSL (with path)). This installed OpenSSL into /usr/local/ssl.
The problem is, I still have files which seem to refer to the old version:

dpkg -L openssl returns:

```
dpkg -L openssl
/.
/usr
/usr/local
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/openssl
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I removed ruby completely and '/usr/local/lib/ruby' does not exist anymore.

If I type 'openssl version' I get the right one:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

But when I try to recompile curl, I still get the wrong one back:

```
curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.49.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Plesk does not find OpenSSL neither.

What can I do to point everything to the right OpenSSL version?

Comment: Leave the system's version of OpenSSL in alone at `/usr`. Compile and link your programs against your version of the OpenSSL library in `/usr/local/ssl`. Use OpenSSL's release information or wiki as a reference, and not someone's blog. OpenSSL's has the information in its various INSTALL files. The wiki has the information at [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).